# How do you control an HSLA alpha channel in a SCSS color function?

Tags: html, css, sass, colors

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this. Basically I want the function to pass through the alpha channel of the hsla color in the color variable so I don't have to have multiple color variables for each color.

I'd like to be able to call the function like this:

```
.item {background-color: color(blue, dark, .5);}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
$base-blue:    hsla(200,100%,50%,1);
$base-blue-50: hsla(200,100%,50%,.5);

$palette: (
    blue: (
        base:  $base-blue,
        light: lighten($base-blue, 10%),
        dark:  darken($base-blue, 10%)
    ),
     blue-50: (
        base:  $base-blue-50,
        light: lighten($base-blue-50, 10%),
        dark:  darken($base-blue-50, 10%)
    )
);

@function color($color, $tone: 'base') {
    @return map-get(map-get($palette, $color), $tone);
}
```

Basically I don't want to have to create the `$base-blue-50` variable if I don't have to.

Thanks for your help with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `$base-blue` using `hsl` instead of `hsla`, you can adjust its alpha value dynamically within your `color()` function.

```scss
$base-blue: hsl(200, 100%, 50%);

$palette: (
    blue: (
        base:  $base-blue,
        light: lighten($base-blue, 10%),
        dark:  darken($base-blue, 10%)
    )
);

@function color($color, $tone: 'base', $a: 1) {
    $rgb: map-get(map-get($palette, $color), $tone);
    @return rgba($rgb, $a); // Apply the alpha value
}

.item {
    color: color(blue);            // Output: #00aaff
    color: color(blue, light);     // Output: #33bbff
    color: color(blue, dark);      // Output: #0088cc
    color: color(blue, dark, .5);  // Output: rgba(0, 136, 204, 0.5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you need to return hsla, this option does the job by directly changing the alpha channel
@use 'sass:color';

@function alpha($color-name, $new-alpha: 100) {
  $map: map-merge(map-get($themes, 'light'), $colors);
  $color: map-get($map, $color-name);

  @if $color == null {
    @warn "Color `#{$color-name}` is not defined in theme";
    @return null;
  }

  @return color.change($color, $alpha: calc($new-alpha / 100));
}
```

// return hsla

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).